# Can't seem to match elements of WHERE clause of SQL statement using RegEx

Tags: c#, .net, regex, perl

I have this "WHERE" clause:

```
WHERE 1 = 0 AND 0 = 1 AND A = B
```

I created the following regular expression:

```
\s*(?<SearchCondition>[^,]+?)\s*(?<Connector>(AND|OR|$))
```

which will create the groups properly when the input string is:

```
1 = 0 AND 0 = 1 AND A = B
```

but how would I adapt it to give the same result when given the string:

```
SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE WHERE 1 = 0 AND 0 = 1 AND A = B
```

I was trying to stick "WHERE" in front of my regex but I can't figure out how to get it right. I was trying this out in regexhero: 
http://regexhero.net/tester/

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Your setup and goal are unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just match the part before `WHERE` and make it as optional to work on both lines,

```
(?:\s+|.*?(?=\S+ \d))?(?<SearchCondition>[^,]+?)\s*(?<Connector>(AND|OR|$))
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aO5dB0/10)